# is convex hull of intersection equal to intersection of convex hull

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

is $convexhull(S_1\cap S_2)=convexhull(S_1)\cap convexhull(S_2)$

where $S_1$ and $S_2$ are finite sets.

Comment: $S_1=\{(0,1),(0,-1)\}$. $S_2=\{(1,0),(-1,0)\}$.

Comment: i guess it is true for this set.in both case it is centre

Comment: No. $S_1\cap S_2=\emptyset$.

Comment: oh sorry i missed it,thanks

Answer (score 5):

No, for example consider $S_1=\{1,3\}$, $S_2=\{2\}$. The intersection is empty, and the intersection of convex hulls is $S_2$.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no. For example the following two subsets of the plane[image]

Comment: These don't look finite.